# Devise and Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to integrate Devise with Omniauth and have some troubles with them both. The main problem is to bind Devise User model with Omniauth authentications. I want a simple way to associate my user, with external providers like facebook, twitter, g+ and so on.

One of the most annoying issues that arise with my application is:

If an user registered on my site with devise (I call it local user), that means, provided an email and a password, when user tries to login with twitter, the system asks for mail confirmation. If that mail already exists, then user have to provide another mail. I want instead that he can confirm with a password that it is actually his email. How to do that? How can I override that template?

This is my authentications controller:

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @authentications = Authentication.all
  end

  def create
    @authentication = Authentication.new(params[:authentication])
    if @authentication.save
      redirect_to authentications_url, :notice => "Successfully created authentication."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @authentication = Authentication.find(params[:id])
    @authentication.destroy
    redirect_to authentications_url, :notice => "Successfully destroyed authentication."
  end 

  def twitter
    omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'], omni['uid'])

    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in Successfully"
      sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
    elsif current_user

      token = omni['credentials'].token
      token_secret = omni['credentials'].secret


      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omni['provider'], :uid => omni['uid'], :token => token, :token_secret => token_secret)
      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      sign_in_and_redirect current_user
    else

      user = User.new 
      user.apply_omniauth(omni)

      if user.save

        flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
        sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)             
      else

        session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
        p session
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

I also have no idea where `new_users_registration_path` is.

Comment: The `new_users_registration_path` routes to `http://yourhost/users/sign_up`.

Comment: Thanks but I meant that I don't know where the template is.

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation? You can find basically every answer to your questions there (or on the ancillary wiki pages): https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started

Comment: Yes, I did but still don't know how to solve my problem. I'm fairly new to Ruby and there are a lot of issues that I have to solve.

Comment: @Arey : read this [configuring view](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views). If you want template of devise you should run `rails generate devise:views`

Comment: I did that too before posting. I just cannot figure out how to bind accounts.